# Regex match, quite simple:

Tags: regex, twitter

I'm looking to match Twitter syntax with a regex.

How can I match anything that is `"@______"` that is, begins with an @ symbol, and is followed by no spaces, just letters and numbers until the end of the word? (To tweeters, I want to match someone's name in a reply)

Comment: In the future, it may be useful when asking RegEx questions to note the dialect you are using-- .NET, Perl, ECMAScript/JavaScript, etc. There are some subtle differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for

> `/@(\w+)/`

to get the matching name extracted as well.

Comment: Al this solution are not useful because if you test something like @@ or @h* which are invalid for twitter accounts these are marked as valid expressions with the regexp offered above

Comment: This will only work for a certain set of valid names. It will not work for I18N names. Twitter provides a very extensive REGEX to handle it.

Comment: @JohnYeary `Twitter provides a very extensive REGEX to handle it`, can you please provide link for it?

Comment: You can find the official Twitter Regex library here: [Regex.java](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java)

Answer (score 5):

`@\w+`

That simple?

Comment: You need a \ in front of your w - and you'd probably want to use +, not * (since an @ without a name isn't valid).

Comment: I had a slash in there, must've nuked it when I changed the * to a +

Comment: @DOK: POSIX standard regex says that \w should match alphanumerics and underscores.

Comment: As Dav mentioned, \w is generally equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_] - but worth noting that some regex engines also include accented characters (i.e. á/ê/ö and so on) in their 'word character' definition. Good idea to quickly test whatever regex flavour is being used, if this might cause an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that Twitter no longer allows usernames longer than 15 characters, so you can also match with:

```
@\w{1,15}
```

There are still apparently a few people with usernames longer than 15 characters, but testing on 15 would be better if you want to exclude *likely* false positives.

There are apparently no rules regarding whether underscores can be used the the beginning or end of usernames, multiple underscores, etc., and there are accounts with single-letter names, as well as someone with the username "_".

Answer (score 0):

```
@[\d\w]+
```

\d for a digit character
\w for a word character
[] to denote a character class
+ to represent more than one instances of the character class

Note that these specifiers for word and digit characters are language dependent.  Check the language specification to be sure.

Comment: \w actually includes digits, so @\w+ will suffice.

Comment: The other answer with just "\w" is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very extensive API for how to get valid twitter names, mentions, etc. The Java version of the API provided by Twitter can be found on github [twitter-text-java](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java). You may want to take a look at it to see if this is something you can use.

I have used it to validate Twitter names and it works very well.